# How to display image correctly from link ? ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, ios8, png

I am using this code to display the images on my ios app :

```
NSData *receivedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
 self.image=nil;
 UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData ];
 self.image = img;
```

this code work perfect for many images , but it can't display this image :
https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0Bw8vnOWKrLfgUmc3aHBkczkwbjQ&export=download

also my android app display it correctly !

what's the problem ?

EDIT :
I would mention that i can't open the image on my mac preview , it shows this message : It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize. but I can open it with chrome.

Comment: Please add Android code. This will help me to understand why it works there.

Comment: @Misha I'm using this library https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Answer (score 1):

Your image isn't valid png file. Actually it's [WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) image. It's supported by Google Chrome, but OS X or iOS doesn't have native support for this format, so that's why your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the link is not an image, it redirects to another link which is also not an image.

Comment: I can download the image from the link you corrected, but cannot display it in windows - it says it is corrupted.

Comment: but you can open it using your chrome ! also try to upload it to your google drive and you will see that you can open it.

Comment: Sorry but I can't open that image with any system.

Comment: maybe because you are using windows any i am using mac. anyway thank you for your time and help.